# Looking at iteration of a function to generate a random password to a maximum of 3 times

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I am new to Programming and am looking for a nudge or some tips into the right direction with an iteration. I am trying to create looping for a random password generator I have created.

I need the function to loop 3 times and I'm aware some of the code is incorrect as I was just trying to see what I could get to work, I'm open to anything you guys throw my way - I will be posting the code below. :)

```js
//Function to generate and display to console Word 1 - random number
function Word1() {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
    return random
}
```

```js
// function to generate and display to console Word 2 - random emotion
function Word2() {
    var emotions = [ 'sad', 'happy', 'cheerful', 'angry', 'fear', 'surprise'];
    return emotions[Math.floor(Math.random()*emotions.length)];
}
```

```js
//function to generate and display to console Word 3 - random plural noun
function Word3() {
    var emotions = [ 'computer', 'day', 'car', 'flower', 'house', 'cat'];
    var plural = ['s'];
    var random = emotions[Math.floor(Math.random()*emotions.length)];
    var emotion_plural = random + plural;
    return emotion_plural
}
```

```js
//function to generate and display to console Word 4 - random verb
function Word4() {
    var verbs = [ 'running', 'walking', 'sleeping', 'talking', 'singing', 'sitting'];
    return verbs[Math.floor(Math.random()*verbs.length)];
}
```

```js
// function to create password one-line string
function passWord() {
    return `${Word1()} ${Word2()} ${Word3()} ${Word4()}`
    //console.log(passWord());
}
```

Comment: "I need the function to loop 3 times". Sounds like you need a for loop somewhere, then. But also, *which* function?

Comment: @solarshado The password generator function mentioned above, sorry if i was not clear enough, the entire code is to give out random words and the last one is to print out all 4 other functions to generate a random password, i need to get the entire function "the random password generator" to loop 3 times, my OP was asking for advice on direction for getting it to loop a random password 3 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code wasnt off to a terrible start for being basic.  You had some typos...  Javascript variable and function names are case sensitive.

I also broke out some of the variables just to make the process more "readable".  Its not overall how I would do everything, but I kept to your initial stab at it.

```js
var Word1 = function() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
  return randomNumber
};

var Word2 = function() {
  var emotions = ['sad', 'happy', 'cheerful', 'angry', 'fear', 'surprise'];
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * emotions.length);
  var randomEmotion = emotions[randomNumber];
  return randomEmotion;
};

var Word3 = function() {
  var nouns = ['computer', 'day', 'car', 'flower', 'house', 'cat'];
  var plural = 's';
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * nouns.length);
  var randomNoun = nouns[randomNumber];
  var pluralRandomNoun = randomNoun + plural;
  return pluralRandomNoun;
};

var Word4 = function() {
  var verbs = ['running', 'walking', 'sleeping', 'talking', 'singing', 'sitting'];
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * verbs.length);
  var randomVerb = verbs[randomNumber];
  return randomVerb;
};

var passWord = function() {
  var randomPassword = Word1() + Word2() + Word3() + Word4();
  return randomPassword;
};

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  console.log(passWord());
}
```

Comment: thank you for this and for taking it easy on me, im very new to this world, its struggle to learn but im doing my best, this has worked and i didn't know you could do it that way.

Comment: no worries... we all start somewhere.  In the future, when you post questions, they like you to be a little more specific with what is not working...   You said it wasn't working... but you didn't say what error you were getting, where it was coming from, or what unexpected output you were getting etc...

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I'll be sure to be as descriptive as possible in the future.